# High precision multidimensional Newtons method with mpmath.findroot in Python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, newtons-method, mpmath

I am trying to solve a system of equations numerically to high precision using the multidimensional newtons method of mpmath.findroot. Here's an example system:

```
def f(x_0, x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5, y_0, y_1, y_2, y_3, y_4, y_5, l_0, l_1,l_2, l_3, l_4, l_5, l_6, l_7, l_8, l_9, l_10, l_11, l_12, l_13, l_14):
    return -x_0, -y_0 + 1, -x_5, -y_5, -x_1 - x_2, -y_1 + y_2, -x_3 - x_4, -y_3 + y_4, -(x_1 - x_5)^2 - (y_1 - y_5)^2 + 1, -(x_1 - x_4)^2 - (y_1 - y_4)^2 + 1, -(x_0 - x_5)^2 - (y_0 - y_5)^2 + 1, -(x_3 - x_4)^2 - (y_3 - y_4)^2 + 1, -(x_2 - x_3)^2 - (y_2 - y_3)^2 + 1, -(x_2 - x_5)^2 - (y_2 - y_5)^2 + 1, -(x_0 - x_5)^2 - (y_0 - y_5)^2 + 1, 2*l_10*(x_0 - x_5) + 2*l_14*(x_0 - x_5) + l_0 - .5*y_1 + .5*y_2, 2*l_9*(x_1 - x_4) + 2*l_8*(x_1 - x_5) + l_4 + .5*y_0 - .5*y_3, 2*l_12*(x_2 - x_3) + 2*l_13*(x_2 - x_5) - .5*y_0 + .5*y_4, -2*l_12*(x_2 - x_3) + 2*l_11*(x_3 - x_4) + l_6 + .5*y_1 - .5*y_5, -2*l_9*(x_1 - x_4) - 2*l_11*(x_3 - x_4) - .5*y_2 + .5*y_5, -2*l_10*(x_0 - x_5) - 2*l_14*(x_0 - x_5) - 2*l_8*(x_1 - x_5) - 2*l_13*(x_2 - x_5) + l_2 + .5*y_3 - .5*y_4, 2*l_10*(y_0 - y_5) + 2*l_14*(y_0 - y_5) + l_1 + .5*x_1 - .5*x_2, 2*l_9*(y_1 - y_4) + 2*l_8*(y_1 - y_5) + l_5 - .5*x_0 + .5*x_3, 2*l_12*(y_2 - y_3) + 2*l_13*(y_2 - y_5) + .5*x_0 - .5*x_4, -2*l_12*(y_2 - y_3) + 2*l_11*(y_3 - y_4) + l_7 - .5*x_1 + .5*x_5, -2*l_9*(y_1 - y_4) - 2*l_11*(y_3 - y_4) + .5*x_2 - .5*x_5, -2*l_10*(y_0 - y_5) - 2*l_14*(y_0 - y_5) - 2*l_8*(y_1 - y_5) - 2*l_13*(y_2 - y_5) + l_3 - .5*x_3 + .5*x_4
import sage.libs.mpmath.all as mpmath
startsol=[0, -0.345847373297000, 0.345847770952000, -0.499999005131000, 0.500000393924000, 0, 0.999999726908000, 0.938291180327000, 0.938290404618000, 0.404864576964000, 0.404866700310000, 0, 0, 0.0205563218420000, 0.00287356421947000, -0.0200611112418000, 0.00371301649518000, 0.00363938213640000, -0.00658839856658000, -0.00414258257348000, 0.0391290458552000, 0.162094656373000, 0.0813226022151000, 0.0974643704937000, 0.158202488927000, 0.0432804352887000, 0.0813226022151000]
print f(*startsol)
mpmath.mp.dps=100
ans=mpmath.findroot(f, startsol)
```

Unfortunately it does not give me a solution but throws an error

> ZeroDivisionError: matrix is numerically singular

Is this happening because findroot is trying to calculate the jacobian? Does this mean that the system is underdetermined?

I found the starting point using scipy's fmin_cg, but I want to polish the solution to higher precision. As a function for fmin_cg I minimized the sum of squares of the 27 entries of my function f.

If the problem with mpmath.findroot cannot be avoided, is there better way to solve this system to high precision?

Comment: Are you aware that in writing, eg, `-(x_1 - x_5)^2`, you are performing xor and *not* exponentiation?  The power operator in Python is `**`.

Comment: @sapi thanks. I am using mpmath from with sage, which does some presarsing, and you are absolutely right: I want exponentiation! If I replace '^' by '**' it still gives the same error (and in sage it is the same thing..)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the system is underdetermined, its Jacobian matrix has rank 24 (at most) instead of 27. You can check this using SymPy:

```
import sympy as sp
vars = sp.var('x_0, x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5, y_0, y_1, y_2, y_3, y_4, y_5, l_0, l_1,l_2, l_3, l_4, l_5, l_6, l_7, l_8, l_9, l_10, l_11, l_12, l_13, l_14')
F = sp.Matrix([-x_0, -y_0 + 1, -x_5, -y_5, -x_1 - x_2, -y_1 + y_2, -x_3 - x_4, -y_3 + y_4, -(x_1 - x_5)**2 - (y_1 - y_5)**2 + 1, -(x_1 - x_4)**2 - (y_1 - y_4)**2 + 1, -(x_0 - x_5)**2 $
J = F.jacobian(vars)
print(J.rank())
```

Looking more carefully at the Jacobian matrix shows what the redundant equations are. For example, these are equations numbered 0-3 and 10:

```
-x_0      = 0 
-y_0 + 1  = 0
-x_5      = 0
-y_5      = 0 
-(x_0 - x_5)^2 - (y_0 - y_5)^2 + 1  = 0
```

Clearly, the last one is a consequence of the first four. This redundancy needs to go away.

#### Using symbolic Jacobian

If mpmath.findroot is not given a function computing the Jacobian, it will use numeric differentiation, introducing additional errors. If available, it is better to provide a Jacobian function. Here is a small code sample for completeness.

```
import sympy as sp
import mpmath as mp
vars = sp.var('x, y, z')
F = [x**2 + y**3 + z**4 - 6, x + y + z - 2, 3*x**2 + y - 5]
J = sp.Matrix(F).jacobian(vars)
f = lambda x0,y0,z0 : [Fc.subs(list(zip(vars, [x0,y0,z0]))) for Fc in F]
Jac = lambda x0,y0,z0 : J.subs(list(zip(vars, [x0,y0,z0]))).tolist()
start = [1, 1, 1]
print(mp.findroot(f, start, J = Jac))
```